# How can I change ImageField widget in Mezzanine to use Media library browser?

Tags: django, django-admin, mezzanine, django-models

When I use common Source class definition like

```
class Source(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=...)
    ...
```

I get the common dialog in the administration module which shows currenty assigned photo or empty field. In the latter case I am able to select the photo from the file browser operating on local disk.

If I change the blog picture, I am able to assign only the photos downloaded to media library and available through Media library browser.

What should I do to be able to select a photo from Media library browser also for ordinary ImageField?

Why are there two ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by using FileField instead of ImageField.

```py
from mezzanine.core import fields

class Source(models.Model):
    photo = fields.FileField("Image", upload_to="dir/", format="Image")
```

Digging through the code a bit, I found that Mezzanine's 'FileField' is just an abstraction for filebrowser's 'FileBrowserField' if it exists, otherwise it falls back to the default django FileField.  I don't know why they didn't make it work for ImageField as well.  FileBrowserField is smart enough to look it up from the media library, FileField is not.  So you will also need to have filebrowser_safe installed.

Comment: Is there a way to use ImageField in Mezzanine? I want to, compulsorily use ImageField from django instead of FileField. How do I?